# Setting virtualenv and install Django (MACOSX)

Tags: django, web

I don't know why I can't create virutalenv for my projects.

I create the folder and type the command to install Django

> pipenv install Django

But I have an error I can't identify what is it.

> Warning: the environment variable LANG is not set! We recommend
>   setting this in ~/.profile (or equivalent) for proper expected
>   behavior. Creating a virtualenv for this project... Pipfile:
>   /Users/pedrosantos/Desktop/helloworld/Pipfile Using
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
>   (3.6.6) to create virtualenv... ⠋Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py",
>   line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py",
>   line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/pew/**main**.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       import pew   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pew/**init**.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       from . import pew   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pew/pew.py",
>   line 44, in 
>       from pew._utils import (check_call, invoke, expandpath, own, env_bin_dir,   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pew/_utils.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       encoding = locale.getlocale()[1] or 'ascii'   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/locale.py",
>   line 581, in getlocale
>       return _parse_localename(localename)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/locale.py",
>   line 490, in _parse_localename
>       raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename) ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
>
> Virtualenv location:  Creating a Pipfile for this project... Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pipenv", line
>   11, in 
>       sys.exit(cli())   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py",
>   line 722, in **call**
>       return self.main(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py",
>   line 697, in main
>       rv = self.invoke(ctx)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py",
>   line 1066, in invoke
>       return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py",
>   line 895, in invoke
>       return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py",
>   line 535, in invoke
>       return callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli.py",
>   line 435, in install
>       selective_upgrade=selective_upgrade,   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py",
>   line 1759, in do_install
>       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py",
>   line 639, in ensure_project
>       ensure_pipfile(validate=validate, skip_requirements=skip_requirements, system=system)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py",
>   line 288, in ensure_pipfile
>       project.create_pipfile(python=python)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/project.py",
>   line 607, in create_pipfile
>       required_python = self.which('python')   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py",
>   line 115, in which
>       p = os.path.join(location, 'bin', command)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py",
>   line 80, in join
>       a = os.fspath(a) TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

So sorry, I am beginner in Django and I am following the Willian S. Vicent book (Django 2.0)

After that the book ask to type:

> $ pipenv shell

and start my project. I could do it before, but now I don't know what is happening.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue in MacOS, The issue is mentioned here a long with  the solution.
https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/diagnose/#valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8

To make the long story short, There are some variables are missing in your machine which are `LC_ALL` and `LANG`. You have to add this to your `~/.bash_profile` file.

so what you need to do is open this file with your favorit editor and add those line

```
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
```

After you add those Env Variables, you will need to re activate this file. So you need to run

`> source ~/.bash_profile`